# display colors from systemd in ssh session to embedded device

Tags: ssh, terminal, systemd

I have a embedded device to which I connect to with a ssh terminal. When running systemd* commands the output contains color characters like shown below:

[[0;1;32m●[[0m reMarkable
State: [[0;1;32mrunning[[0m

I know I can turn the color off with export SYSTEMD_COLORS=0, but is it possible to configure my host terminal to display the colors correctly?

I have tried with putty, teraterm and standard linux terminal in Ubuntu. Can't find any way to display the colors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with pager used by systemd on embedded device. Systemd uses `less -FRSXMK` by default.
BusyBox `less` may not support colors (i.e. `-R` option).
 You can use other pager (`export SYSTEMD_PAGER="more"`) or install `less` from a different package.